# Live Radio on WordPress.com Blog

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get a live radio stream to play on my WordPress (.com) blog. Is there a widget I could use to achieve this? Can I use the RSS widget to accomplish this? I tried pasting the live stream link into this widget but the station's blog feed displayed on my blog. Any assistence will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress.com is very limited in terms of what you can do. See [Audio « Support — WordPress.com](http://en.support.wordpress.com/audio/). If you want to stream audio, you need your own self-hosted Wordpress site: [Getting Started with WordPress at Wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress)